# UITabBarController with many UINavigationControllers?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I need some help figuring out the anatomy of my app.

What I need is a tab bar that also have a top navigation bar. And then each view controller within the tab bar will need to have buttons that can transition in new views within this tab. Does that make sense?

So my question is, how should I set this up. Should it be a main tabarviewcontroller and then each view has a separate nagivationcontroller? Or should it be a navigation controller that has the tab bar as a root. And then just use that navigation controller to do any transitions within the viewcontroller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main view can be a UITabBarController, and you can add your UINavigationControllers to the tab bar viewControllers array. Each navigation controller will have a separate navigation bar and function independently. Clicking on a tab will switch to the appropriate navigation controller.